# PHP Fatal Error: "Can't use method return value in write context in.... "

Tags: php

Trying to use a class that expects something like:

```
$client->firstname = 'bob';

$client->lastname = 'jones';
```

So I want to pass this data to the script in an array... where the keys and values are set elsewhere.  I want to step through the array passing the key and value to the class.  Trying to use this:

```
while($Val = current($CreateClientData)){

    $client->key($CreateClientData) = $Val;
    next($CreateClientData);
}
```

getting this:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   blahblahpath on line 40.
>
> Line 40 being: $client->key($CreateClientData) = $Val;

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If $client is already an instance of some class, and $CreateClientData is an array, then you probably wan to do something like this:

```
foreach($CreateClientData as $k => $v) {
    $client->{$k} = $v;
}
```

This assumes of course that every key in the array is a valid member of the $client instance.  If not, then you will have to do some additional checking before assigning the value, or you will have to wrap the assignment in a try / catch.

**EDIT**
The answer as to why your code doesn't work is because PHP doesn't allow for assignment of class properties to certain functions that return values.  In your case, `key($CreateClientData)` returns a key.  So you could alter your code and just add

```
$key = key($CreateClientData);
$client->$key = $Val;
```

But, the foreach loop is a lot cleaner anyway.

Comment: Perfect.  I had never worked with keys inside of a foreach.  Thanks for excusing my ignorance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a foreach loop?

```
foreach($CreateClientData as $key => $val) {
    $client->$key = $val;
}
```